# fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) what is the use of this in gui in java

Tags: java

fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

I want to proper explanation of it (fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)) why we use it

Comment: According the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) - *"EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications."*.  To understand why you might use, you need to understand under what conditions the JVM "normally" exists (of its own accord). The JVM will exit (normally) when the only remaining running threads are `daemon` threads.

Comment: Swing will also stop the event dispatching thread when the last window is "disposed", which will allow the the JVM to exit "normally".  You "might" use `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` if you know that you will have some non-daemon threads left running after a user closes the window and you want the JVM to exit anyway

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.